# StackDriver fallback metric value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I'm trying to monitor my instances by uptime, and alert when it's less than 1.
But when I delete the instance, the metrics don't match the condition. It seems that it's not 0, it's rather 'null'

So, is there a possibility to regard no metrics as 0 ?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include more details about your use case to help us assist you better. You can refer to [how-to-doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for assistance.  If possible provide information about your configuration to see if we can reproduce the same issue.

Comment: What is missing? This is like, the `Hello World` of alerts..

Comment: It seems like you would like to be alerted based on metric absence for an instance metric and you would like the deletion of the instance to trigger the alert as well. Stackdriver doesn't trigger alerts for stopped or deleted instances. If you are trying to detect that the instance is down, the currently preferred approach is to perform an "uptime" check on a service that the VM exposes.

Comment: Since this is not possible at this time, I would recommend that you submit a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Google will consider the need based on its feasibility, or the number of customers who ask for it, but they can't guarantee an implementation or provide you with an ETA for it.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690620 ?